# Elasticsearch: Schema without mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

According to Elasticsearch's [roadmap](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html), mapping types are going to be completely removed at 7.x

How are we going to give a schema structure to Documents without mapping?

For example how would we replace this (A Doc/mapping_type with 3 fields of specific data type):

```
PUT twitter
{
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "properties": {
        "name": { "type": "text" },
        "user_name": { "type": "keyword" },
        "email": { "type": "keyword" }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are going to remove types (`user` in you example) from mapping, because there is only 1 type per index now, the rest will be the same:

```
PUT twitter
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": { "type": "text" },
        "user_name": { "type": "keyword" },
        "email": { "type": "keyword" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, there is no `user` type anymore.

Comment: What I undestand is that Elasticsearch 5->6 includes single mapping type transition and 6->7 no types at all. Is the above compatible with elasticsearch 7.x? Thanks

Comment: 5 allows multiple types, 6 allows only 1 type per index, 7 deprecates type, introducing _doc placeholder instead, 8 removes types completely. The query above will work in 7. This is described in the doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation. Going a bit off-topic here: Is there a way to make the above mapping compatible also to 5.x (where _doc is undefined)? I forgot to ask this in the original question :(

Comment: you can't create a type with underscore in 5.x, but you can choose different one, as described in the documentation : `The preferred type name is _doc, so that index APIs have the same path as they will have in 7.0:`

Comment: If you choose a different one (e.g `mytype`) that would not be compatible with 7.x. That quoted text is for 6.x I think, because as you said we can't have underscore in 5.x. If I misunderstood your last comment, ignore this :)